# Twofish and Threefish encryption in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, encryption

How do I encrypt a string with twofish or threefish via a bash script in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gpg`:

```
gpg -c --cipher-algo twofish --passphrase=123 myfile
```

- `-c`: encrypt  with a symmetric cipher using a passphrase.
- `--cipher-algo` : twofish
- `--passphrase=123`: set the passphares to 123
- `file` name of the file

Then check the file type:

```
$ file myfile.gpg
myfile.gpg: GPG symmetrically encrypted data (TWOFISH cipher)
```

For `stdin` you can just pip it to `gpg`:

```
echo hi bla bla | gpg -c --cipher-algo twofish --passphrase=123 > file.gpg
```

or for a variable:

```
gpg -c --cipher-algo twofish --passphrase=123 > file.gpg <<<"$var"
```

Comment: He was thinking more OPENSSL

Comment: I'm not aware how it can be done using openssl, however I updated to support non-interactive mode, so OP will be able to use it in scripts.

Comment: Statically setting the passphrase is not very secure. There are ways to pipe using fd's which are a bit more secure. (Or at the bare minimum, at least recommend that the script be readable by only the intended user...)